# Problem with kotlin receiver when converting from java

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm trying to convert a java class into a kotlin class

```
    @Override
    protected Context constructContext(long entityId, String author, String changesSetId) {
        Context context = constructDefaultContext(author, changesSetId);
        try (Connection connection = datasourceConfig.getDataSource().getConnection()) {
            try (Statement stm = connection.createStatement()) {
                try(ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("select * from modules where id = " + entityId)){
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        ModuleDto moduleDto = constructModuleDto(rs);
                        context.put("module", moduleDto);
                    } else
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No module with id: " + entityId);
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throw new RuntimeException(throwables);
        }
        return context;    }
```

the intellij conversion produces

```
override fun constructContext(entityId: Long, author: String, changesSetId: String): Context {
        val context = constructDefaultContext(author, changesSetId)
        try {
            datasourceConfig.dataSource!!.connection.use { connection ->
                connection.createStatement().use { stm ->
                    stm.executeQuery(
                        "select * from modules where id = $entityId"
                    ).use { rs ->
                        if (rs.next()) {
                            val moduleDto = constructModuleDto(rs)
                            context.put("module", moduleDto)
                        } else throw IllegalArgumentException("No module with id: $entityId")
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (throwables: SQLException) {
            throw RuntimeException(throwables)
        }
        return context
    }
```

But when I build it, I get the following error:

Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:

```
public inline fun <T : Closeable?, R> TypeVariable(T).use(block: (TypeVariable(T)) -> TypeVariable(R)): TypeVariable(R) defined in kotlin.io
```

Pointing at this line:

```
datasourceConfig.dataSource!!.connection.use { connection ->
```

I admit I'm stumped and any advice would be greatly appreciated...

EDIT:

dataSourceConfig is a simple class to get a datasource, that I had converted using the Intellij converter at an earlier date:

```
class DatasourceConfig {
    var ds: DataSource? = null

    @get:Throws(SQLException::class)
    val dataSource: DataSource?
        get() {
            if (null == ds) {
                val state = CodeGenerationConfigState.instance
                val mySQLDataSource = MysqlDataSource()
                mySQLDataSource.setUrl(String.format("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/%s", state.dbName))
                mySQLDataSource.user = state.username
                mySQLDataSource.password = state.password
                ds = mySQLDataSource
            }
            return ds
        }
}
```

and context is a VelocityContext

Comment: What is `datasourceConfig`? and what type is your `context` variable?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've edited the question

Comment: I could be misunderstanding the code, but seems like the `use` keyword doesn't exist and based on how the Java looks, it seems replacing `use` with `let` might do what you want?

Comment: Is that Spring? Just ignore the converter and port it. The Lambda is being passed the wrong type for certain. `.use {}` probably just cannot be used with that type. This issue generally has to do with reflection: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/lang/reflect/TypeVariable

Comment: My understanding is that that "use" keyword is the kotlin equivalent of java's "try-with-resources": https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html

Comment: It is not about the `use` keyword, but the type which is being passed into the Lambda - and by avoiding the use of Lambda syntax, this might eventually work as intended.

Comment: @MartinZeitler No, it's just straight jdbc, not Spring. But yeah, I guess porting it manually is what I'll have to do - just feels wrong to have to explicitly close simple autocloseable jdbc classes like Connection, Statement and Resultset

Comment: That `dataSource` property shouldn't be nullable. Then you won't have to use `!!`.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems I needed to include the kotlin jdk 8 libraries in my gradle build file:

```
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
```